# HashMap <String ,Class>

Tags: java, hashmap

I have an HashMap and i would like to print all the key values and the attributes of the classes.
My class is:

```
class Country {
    String country;
    int population;

Country(String  country, int population) {
    this.country=country;
    this.population=population;
  }
}
```

I want to create hashMap where Integer will the year for example from 2010 to 2014, and the class country will be all the countries and population for that year, and later print that HashMap, by year and retreiving the country name and population.

```
int year=1960;
HashMap<Integer,Country> country =new HashMap<Integer, Country>();
for (int j=0; j<10; j++)                                        
{
    String country=countrylist[j]);    
    int population=populationlist[j]);     
    Country P=new Country(country,population);      
    country.put(year, P);         

    year++;

}

for (Map.Entry p : country.entrySet()) {
    Country country=(Country)p.getValue();
    year=(Integer)p.getKey();
    nameCountry=country.country;
    population=country.population;
    println(year,namecountry,population);
}
```

Comment: ok. what is the question? is there a specific part where you got stuck?

Comment: i am getting only the last class i have introduced, so the last country, when i try to print.

Comment: int year=2010;  Country P=new(countryName,Population) ; Country.put(year,P);

Comment: can you pls show the code relevant to the problem? The part of the logic that's not working as expected?

Comment: the snippet above won't compile. 1) `new(...)` is not valid java syntax 2) if you create a `Country` instance it doesn't have a `put` method. can you just edit the question and paste what you have other than the `Country` pojo?

Comment: this is java for processing and put is a library for processing to insert values on HashMap

Comment: the problem i think it´s the key, because it´s overwriting everytime i make a put with the same key

Comment: @ Rolando Azevedo your year will increment 1 every time then you dont encounter the same key,

Comment: ah yes thats true, so why i am getting only the last country of the list.

Comment: @ Rolando Azevedo can you post your complete code, now your code exist many compile error. e.g `String country=countrylist[j]);`why there exist a *right bracket*, `HashMap<Integer,Country> country =new HashMap<Integer, Country>();`and `String country=countrylist[j]);` duplicate variable name.

Comment: It doesn't look like your data structure is appropriate to the problem you say you want to solve.  The data structure you're using maps a single year to a single country, whereas you are trying to map a year to multiple countries.

Comment: You can map a year to an ArrayList of countries, instead of a single country.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is that you are after a 'multi-map' rather than a 'map'. The distinction is that a 'multi-map' allows you to store multiple values for each key. In your case you want multiple country/population entries for each year.

There is no multi-map implementations in the standard Java API. There are a number of third party implementations. Search for multimap and you'll find a bunch.

It's possible to achieve a similar thing using standard Java by having a collection as the value in the map.

In your case you might want to consider a different data structure. Because a country may only have one population each year, a better structure might be:

```
Map<Integer,Map<String,Integer>> populationData;
```

To store data for a new year, you would do:

```
populationData.put(2017, new HashMap<>());
```

And to store data for a country in a year:

```
populationData.get(2017).put("Botswana", 45982637);
```